# How I set a value in input-select (React.js field) with selenium c#?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

people.

I'm not getting the input-select value (React.js field) with selenium c#. The field get values of services.

Obs: I has try fill field  with SendKeys command, but I don't right.

**It's HTML code:**

```
<div class="Select selectbox-select Select--single is-clearable is-searchable"><div class="Select-control"><span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-2--value"><div class="Select-placeholder">Selecione...</div><div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;"><style>input#undefined::-ms-clear {display: none;}</style><input role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="" aria-haspopup="false" aria-activedescendant="react-select-2--value" value="" style="width: 5px; box-sizing: content-box;"><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 16px; font-family: roboto-regular, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;"></div></div></span><span class="Select-arrow-zone"><span class="Select-arrow"></span></span></div></div>

<div class="Select selectbox-select Select--single is-clearable is-searchable has-value"><div class="Select-control"><span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-2--value"><div class="Select-value"><span class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="react-select-2--value-item">000001 - EST GO</span></div><div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;"><style>input#undefined::-ms-clear {display: none;}</style><input role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="" aria-haspopup="false" aria-activedescendant="react-select-2--value" value="" style="width: 5px; box-sizing: content-box;"><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 16px; font-family: roboto-regular, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;"></div></div></span><span class="Select-clear-zone" title="Clear value" aria-label="Clear value"><span class="Select-clear">×</span></span><span class="Select-arrow-zone"><span class="Select-arrow"></span></span></div></div>
```

**It's my code:**

```
//ParametersPage.cs
 public void preencherCampoProduto(string produto)
        {
            inputSelectProduto.Clicks();
            IWebElement dropdownValue = retornaXpathCamposInputSelect(produto);
            dropdownValue.Clicks();
        }

public IWebElement retornaXpathCamposInputSelect(string valor)
        {
            return driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(text(),'" + valor + "')]"));
        }

//ParametersTest.cs
        [TestMethod]
        public void OLE_testParametrosPreencherConvenio()
        {
            autenticacao.RealizarAutenticacao(usuarioCorreto, senhaCorreta);
            paginaInicial.acessarMenuRemuneracaoCadastroListagem();
            parametro.preencherCampoConvenio("005045 - CARBEL");
            //Assert.IsTrue(alerta.MensagemValidacao().Contains(MSG_RelatorioDataInicioFimForaLimite));
        }
```

Thank, people!!!

Answer (score 0):

try using Actions Class:

IWebElement myElement = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='field_" + SetEnvironmentJourney.EnvironmentControlId + "_" + elementId + "']"));
                Actions act = new Actions(Driver.Instance);
                act.MoveToElement(myElement).Click().Build().Perform();

```
            IWebElement myItem = myElement.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(text(),'" + p + "')]"));
            act.Click(myItem).Build().Perform();
```